# jQuery click function not working on IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get jQuery to do things when I click a DIV. I've given it an ID (Ghost) and when I load the page and click it, nothing happens. If I change the script from "#ghost" to "html" the script works. What's wrong with my syntax here?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vL78vr5m/

```
<body>
<div class = "graveyard">
  <div id="cont">
    <div id="ghost">
      <div class="eye"></div>
      <div class="eye"></div>
      <div id="tickle"></div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
alert("Does this work?");              
$('#ghost').click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```

Comment: You need to include jQuery from left panel. Check updated demo https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vL78vr5m/1/. In your code wrap the code in `ready` or move it to the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: Add jquery https://jsfiddle.net/vL78vr5m/3/ and wrap your function inside document.ready. that will work.

Comment: For future debugging: the JS console is your friend, e.g., stuff like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not definedwindow.onload @ (index):91`

Comment: Oh, wow. I took out the document.ready out because I didn't think it was do anything, but now I've put it back in it works.I must have made a problem with the document.ready originally. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to load jQuery in your JSFiddle.

Adding this works:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It is also good practice to make the functions work first when the page is loaded. You can accomplish that by wrapping it in `$(function() { .. });`, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#ghost').click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
});
```

[**UPDATED FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vL78vr5m/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `JS`  in [document.ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included
>   inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire
>   page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Updated [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vL78vr5m/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("Does this work?");

    $('#ghost').click(function(){
        alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
    });
})  ;
```